# Одним словом "передавати/заповідати у спадок"

Tags: терміни, значення-слів, одним-словом

Знайшов занадто багато синонімів, не розумію, який з них найкраще підходить/чи вони рівноправні:

[Відписувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidpysuvaty): 2. Письмово заповідати кому-небудь своє майно в спадок.

[Заповідати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapovidaty): 1. Висловлювати свою передсмертну волю. (Здається, це ширше. Тобто, саме про волю, до якої може входити і бажання передати комусь майно).

[Записувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapysuvaty): 3. що кому, перен., розм. Залишаючи у спадщину, зробити відповідний письмовий документ; відписати.

[Відказувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidkazuvaty): 2. розм. Заповідати комусь що-небудь перед смертю, залишати в спадок.

Чи я правильно розумію, що найкраще підходить `відписувати`? (На противагу занадто широкому `заповідати` і розмовним `записувати` й `відказувати`)

Чи є ще якесь слово, яке б своїм першим значенням мало саме "заповідати/передавати у спадок"?

Comment: А можете уточнити, чому «заповідати» — занадто широке? Наприклад, Цивільний Кодекс України [використовує](http://code.leschishin.org/cc/cc84.php) саме цей термін як дієслово. Стаття 1226, ч.2: *«Суб'єкт права спільної сумісної власності має право **заповідати** свою частку у праві спільної сумісної власності…»*

Comment: @bytebuster тому що я можу сказати "на смертному одрі він заповів синам ніколи не забувати про велику місію їхньої фамілії", і це не буде про спадок. Тобто, передсмертна воля - це не завжди про спадок.

Comment: @P.Vovk Важливо, який саме "спадок" цікавить Вас. **Заповідати** можна і матеріальне, і нематеріальне, і усно, і письмово. **Відписувати** - майно і письмово. (Згідно  з [Практичним словником синонімів української мови" С. Караванського](http://zosh6.at.ua/praktichnij_slovnik_sinonimiv_ukrajinskoji_movi.pdf)) Та саме в частині матеріального і письмового заповідання ці слова - синоніми. СУМ для [**заповідати**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapovidaty) має необхідне Вам значення хоч не 1 пунктом, та й не 2. А У Караванського  - 1. На противагу **відписувати**, 1 значення якого - *відповідати письмово*.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko ну ви ж самі пишете "заповідати можна і... і... і... і", тобто, моя теза про "заповідати - ширше", начебто, працює, бо "відписувати ... і ...". Не можна у спадок передати людині ДІЮ, чи не так?

Comment: @P.Vovk, я пишу, що саме в частині матеріального і письмового  заповідання *заповідати* і *відписувати* - синоніми. При цьому для *відписувати* - передавати у спадок не основне значення, на чому Ви акцентуєте увагу в запитанні. А от який саме спадок Вас цікавив, трохи незрозуміло із запитання.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko о, я зрозумів. Виходить, що "заповідати" - ширше поняття, але в певному контексті відразу дає зрозуміти, що мова йде про передачу майна чи ідей посмертно, а "відписувати" - більш офіційне/точне поняття, якщо йдеться про спадок, але воно має багато інших конотацій. Тобто, з них жодне точно не передає сенсу, але "заповідати" більше стосується посмертної волі людини, аніж "відписувати". Так?

Comment: @P.Vovk Українське законодавство якраз використовує *заповідати* як юридичний термін на позначення *нотаріально посвідчувати заповіт*, а не *відписувати*. Тобто, *заповідати* дійсно трошки ширше, я цього не заперечувала. Але для *заповідати*  - *оформлювати волю заповідача офіційним правочином* є основним значенням (хоч і в поєднанні із значенням *вислювлювати останню волю*, що може й не оформлюватись офіційно). А для *відписувати* значення *офіційно передавати у спадок* є не основним, хоч і конкретнішим, аніж у *заповідати*, бо не може стосуватися чогось нематеріального.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko дуже-дуже дякую. Я майже точно тепер розумію, де доречніше буде вставити "відписала/в", а де краще залишити "заповіла/вів".

Comment: Відома бабця з котом долучають ще варіант "переписати" у значенні "перезаповісти", змінити вигодонабувача за заповітом, що вже існує письмово чи лише у вигляді проекту-майбутньоспрямованої обіцянки.

Comment: @P.Vovk, дякую, рада, якщо допомогла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«[Заповідати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31613&page=1027)», на мою думку, не занадто широке.

Так, воно має різні значення, але невизначеність між:

- «заповідати *<якась власність, що перейде нащадкам>*» (річ, як правило, описується іменними частинами мови, наприклад — «… ту садибу»)   i
- «заповідати *<якась дія, яку мають зробити нащадки>*» (дія, як правило, описується початковою формою дієслова, наприклад — «… поховати на батьківщині», або конструкцією «щоби …», наприклад — «…, щоби ти завжди піклувався про неї»)

— виникає вкрай рідко. Єдина можлива ситуація невизначеності, по-моєму, це коли дія виражена іменними частинами мови, наприклад — «я заповідаю тобі політ на параплані». Чи на мене наклали моральне *зобов'язання* полетіти на параплані, чи мені в спадок передали *можливість* полетіти на параплані, за яку вже сплатили авансом? Але, на мою думку, так кажуть вкрай рідко.

Використання конструкції «заповідати *<якась власність, що перейде нащадкам>*» не є помилковим, незважаючи на наявність паралельної конструкції «заповідати *<якась дія, яку мають зробити нащадки>*». Спільним між цими конструкціями, на мою думку, є те, що *щось передається*: а що саме — прохання/зобов'язання чи річ/можливість — це вже нюанси.

«[Відписувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13353&page=436)» відрізняється від «заповідати (власність)», на мій погляд, в першу чергу тим, що воно констатує письмову/офіційну передачу. Заповісти (власність), теоретично, можна і на словах — наприклад, якщо суспільство на певному етапі свого розвитку (чи певна спільнота) серйозно ставиться до людського слова, або якщо заповідач просто *ще не встиг* оформити заповіт юридично, лише на словах повідомивши родичів. Тобто «відписати власність» = «**офіційно** заповісти власність».

<sub>Так, «відписувати» не можна використовувати до дії, яку мають зробити нащадки — а-ля «він відписав дочці одружитися протягом року» (точніше, можна, але воно в такому випадку приймає значення просто відповіді в листуванні). Але, на мою думку, це пов'язане не з самою семантикою слова «відписати», а з тим, що письмові передсмертні доручення не мають юридичної сили. Якщо уявити таке суспільство, де передсмертне письмово оформлене слово померлого було б юридично обов'язковим до виконання (не лише в плані передачі майна, а й для якихось інших видів наказів), то в ньому, можливо, можна було б і *відписати <дію, яку мають зробити нащадки>*.</sub>

<sub>«[Відказувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12666&page=418)» і «[записувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31392&page=1021)» в цьому значенні — розмовні.</sub>